# Is my install really missing Spatial Functions in DB2 Spatial Extender?

Tags: database, function, db2

I'm running a number of Spatial Functions in DB2 (11.5 LUW) and getting back errors such as:

```
SQL Error [42884]: No authorized routine named "ST_ENDPOINT" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.31.10
```

This is happening for a number of spatial functions:

- ST_EndPoint
- ST_Relate
- ST_ExteriorRing
- ST_InteriorRingN
- ST_Intersection
- ST_IsRing
- ST_NumGeometries
- ST_NumInteriorRing
- ST_PointN
- ST_Relate
- ST_StartPoint

Other geometry functions seem to work fine and I'm calling them with db2gse. When I look in the database under the db2gse schema, these functions are indeed missing. Do I have a corrupted database here? Or is there some other way to reference these functions?

**UPDATE**

I created a brand new database and enabled it for spatial extensions using:

`db2se enable_db MYDB`

This new database is still missing all the above functions. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the documentation is inaccurate.

The following will work as an example for ST_EndPoint

```
db2gse.ST_EndPoint(TREAT(geomcol AS db2gse.ST_Curve))
```

But it won't work if you don't use the TREAT statement. There's no mention of that in the documentation:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-st-endpoint